# How to Run a batch file in a Remote machine Using ANT?

Tags: ant

I want to run a batch file in a remote machine using ANT. The purpose of this is it solves many tasks once it's done. Some of them  are

1. we can resart a server(Jboss,weblogic,Tomcat,etc)
2. we can run an ant script in a remote machine

...and so on.  With all those commands present in the batch file of a remote machine, this could be executed easily.

Is there a way to achieve to achieve this, please and kindly if any one do know provide a reply with example code

I hope  the answer to this question perhaps useful for many people

Thanks in advance StackOverflow

Comment: for future visitors - using a CI like jenkins may be useful - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use the [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) task. Problem is this assumes you have SSH running on the server.

Your use of the word *batch* file suggests you're running Jboss/weblogic/tomcat on a windows machine? SSH is not a common service on that platform, you'll need to first install it.